# How to know from what fragment I'm returning when using Navigation Component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have four fragments already set up in my app using Navigation Components:

[image]

I can go from MainFragment to MoviesFragment or TrailersFragment as well as from the  UserFragment to one of them.

From the `MainFragment` I can simply navigate to the MoviesFragment fragment using this code:

```
ActionMainFragmentToMoviesFragment action = actionMainFragmentToMoviesFragment();
action.setFromMainFragment(true);
Navigation.findNavController(rootView).navigate(action);
```

To navigate to the TrailersFragment fragment, I'm using similar code. When I use:

```
.setFromMainFragment(true);
```

In MoviesFragment for instance, I can simply get a boolean from the Bundle so I can know from which fragment I'm coming from, either from MainFragmnet or UserFragment and it workd very well.

And here comes the problem. When I want to get from MoviesFragment back to MainFragment, I don't navigate as above, I just press the back button. So the problem is that I don't know in the MainFragment from which fragment I'm returning (MoviesFragment or TrailersFragment).

What should I do to know from which fragment I'm coming from in MainFragment?

Comment: Send an event through a shared ViewModel scoped to the shared NavGraph

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks again for trying to help me but I have no clue on how can I do this :( Can you please provide me an answer for that?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Is that solution using a ViewModel working also in Java or only in Kotlin?

Comment: As coroutines are not involved when using ViewModel, it works both in Java and Kotlin.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I'll give it a try and get you back.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Did it with a shared ViewModel. Thank you!

Comment: @EpicPandaForce If you want, you can add an answer. Was a little tricky but it solved my problem.